# Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int

Tags: php, datetime

Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int

I have new problem :

```
$last_update=0;
foreach($datetimetextresult as $value1){
    $datetime_text = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($value1->datetime));
    $date1 = new DateTime ($datetime_text);
    $text = $value1->text;
    if ($last_update < $date1){
        $last_update=$date1;
        $last_text = $text ; 
    }
}
```

I get this eror:

> "Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int"

Comment: DateTime instances can only be compared to other DateTime instances, not integers.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your `$last_update` to an DateTime-Object before the loop, not to an integer.

Change:

```
$last_update=0;
```

To:

```
$last_update = new DateTime('1900-01-01');
```

Otherwise you try to compare the DateTime-Object in the loops first interation with an Integer (zero).